# What is the meaning of "../" in javascript for windows path?

Tags: javascript, windows, directory

I have written some HTML and js code.
My folder Structure is :

A => B => C .

Folder C contains 'index.html' file and I want to access 'emotion.js'.

A => js => emotion.js is the actual place for emotion.js.

```
"<script src=\"../js/emotion.js\">"
```

I have given the link this way. It is not working actually.

I just want to know what "../" means? It is refers to one step before in the folder structure or the root folder?

Answer (score 3):

../ refers to the parent folder.

If your folder structure is

```
A      
  B
    C
      index.html
  js
    emotion.js
```

Then inside index.html you will need to change the script tag to

```
    <script src="../../js/emotion.js">
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to describe this in detail regarding Node.js

Notes - single (.) - represents same directory , (..) - represents move to parent directory then start navigating the required files

1. First scenario - Both files are in parent directory and are not inside any sub-directory

1.parent_directory/
├── main.js
└── module.js

Here both the mian.js and module.js are in parent directory so If I want to import one main.js into module.js

--> const myMain = require('./main')

Here, a single dot(.) represents that they are in the same parent directory

2. Second scenario - One file is parent directory and another file is inside a sub-directory which is also in parent directory

1.parent_directory/
├── main.js
├── subdirectory/
│   └── module.js
└──

--> If you wan to import module.js inside main.js then,

const myModule = require('./subdirectory/module')

--> But let's suppoe if you want to import main.js into module.js then, you must go

const myMain = require('../main')

--> In this case you are moving up to parent directory and in the parent directory there is main file

-> To run the file you must go into that sub- directory first then you need to run the module.js

3.Third Scenario - If two files are in two different sub-directory and you want to import file from one another then,

1.parent_directory/
├── subdirectory1/
│   └── file1.js
└── subdirectory2/
└── file2.js

const myModule = require('../subdirectory1/file1');

-> Now if you want to execute file2.js you must change the directory to subdirectory 2 other wise it won't even run

--> feel free to correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

../ this will take you up one dir so use this 2 times  eg ../../A/js/emotion.js

or you can use / without .. so this will take you to root no matter where you are .

Answer (score 0):

That means parent path of the current file path.